# Compare ClassFactory.generator property (from mxml) with its original Class

Tags: apache-flex, reflection, actionscript, mxml

I have some components declared in MXML tags, with some properties and event handlers.
For some of them there is the need to re-instantiated, so I came up with the following architecture.

Array of components that will be re-instanciated at some poin:

```
<flint:forms>
    <fx:Component>
        <login:LoginForm loginClick="outerDocument.form_loginClick()" />
    </fx:Component>
    <fx:Component>
        <config:CustomizerWizard close="outerDocument.init()" />
    </fx:Component>
</flint:forms>
```

At some point in my controller when I need a brand new "LoginForm":

```
public var form:LoginForm;
...
form = ReDo(LoginForm);
```

The ReDo function should look like this:

```
public function ReDo(classe:Class):* {

    for each (var factory:ClassFactory in forms) {
        if (factory.generator == classe) return factory.newInstance();
    }
}
```

But it does't work as I would like it to. The class created by the Flex compiler for every  tag its not compatible with the actual class that is declared in it.

I tried to create my own  tag, but the compiler won't let me use it in the same way that  can. (Complains that it's not a container)

Is there a way to use a custom ClassFactory class with a property that I could use in my ReDo function? Like this:

```
<flint:forms>
    <flint:MyComponent type="loginForm">
        <login:LoginForm loginClick="outerDocument.form_loginClick()" />
    </flint:Component>
    <flint:MyComponent type="wizard">
        <config:CustomizerWizard close="outerDocument.init()" />
    </flint:Component>
</flint:forms>
```

Or instead of the custom ClassFactory, try to cast/convert the ClassFactory.generator property to something that can be expected, not some random class name that it has righ now?

### Edit

Instead of comparing both Class variables (which I think it's the best aproach), I could instantiate every component in the list and compare if its the type that I want.

```
public function ReDo(classe:Class):* {

    for each (var factory:ClassFactory in forms) {
        var obj:* = factory.newInstance();
        if (obj is classe) return obj;
        //if (factory.generator == classe) return factory.newInstance();
    }
}
```

That would be the only change in my code, but isn't it wasteful? Would GC be smart enough to cleanup all the obj's that don't pass the "if"?

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly what's the point of all this. Seems overly complicated.  Why not use states?

Comment: I'm using the "Humble Dialog Box" architecture. So the code that I've posted is in my controller. The classes that are in <fx:Component> tags are views that need to be re-instantiated during their lifetime, with their events, states and properties already set.

Comment: Wait wait wait... so you're taking a concept made for *non-visual languages* to a *visual language*?  Yeah, that's not going to fly very well.  Actually, it will probably crash and burn on the side of a mountain and you'll have to eat the pilot's buttocks to survive :P

Comment: I would have to agree with JAX on the complexity of your design.  This sounds more like a question where you think you need to solve problem A and have to do B to get it done so you are asking us about solving problem B.  Do you mind telling us what the exact overall problem you are trying to solve is ?

Comment: @JAX That crash and burn thing was mean, but funny. Guys, I'm not doing something insane, just different. Like this: One package for each Use Case, each Use Case has one MXML component use as a controller, were everything that is needed for that UC is declared by tags (I know it sounds crazy, but keep an open mind). Inside the UC package is its Forms and other screens for user interaction, all dumb, since all the rules are in the controller. The problem that I'm trying to solve here is that some of those screens need to bem re-instantiated at some point in their life, but since they are...

Comment: ... declare as MXML tags in the controller, I kind of can't do that. Thats why I came up with the idea of declaring these screens/components with the <fx:Component> tag, so that I can use my "ReDo" function to easily re-instantiate them but still use all the power that MXML tags can offer. The big problem: How can my ReDo function find them? The answer is in my Edit, but I think there is room for improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make events **buddle** and move handlers a level higher:

```
addEventListener(LoginEvent.LOGIN_CLICK, ...);
addEventListener(WizardEvent.CLOSE, ...);
```

then you can write basically:

```
<flint:forms>
    <login:LoginForm id="loginForm" />
    <config:CustomizerWizard id="wizard" />
</flint:forms>
```

And then:

```
public function ReDo(classe:Class):* {
    return new classe();
}
```

Another (and more correct) approach is using a separate factory function for each component:

```
public function createLoginForm():LoginForm {
    var loginForm:LoginForm = new LoginForm();
    loginForm.addEventListener(LoginEvent.LOGIN_CLICK, ...);
    return loginForm;
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. There are a lot of properties and events to be set, I wouldn't like to do that by ActionScript, MXML looks much cleaner. But your ReDo function gave me an idea. (see my edit)